# php insert return data with jquery ajax and fade effection

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fade

I am making a php mysql insert with jquery ajax. Now I want add an effection: If insert success or not, there will also load the html from `ajax process page` with fadein and fadeout. How to modify? thanks.

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
        var formvalue = $("#content").val();
        var url = 'submit=1&content=' + escape(formvalue);
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "2.php",
           data: url,
           success: function(){
           $("#content").val('');
           $("#comment").fadeIn(1000, function () {
              $("#comment").html(html);
              });
           $("#comment").fadeOut(1000, function () {
              $("#comment").html('');
              });
           }
         });
        return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<form id="form" action="2.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea> <br />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add comment" />
</form>
<div id="comment"></div>
```

2.php

```
<?php
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root' , 'root') or die(mysql_error());
    $selection = mysql_select_db('my_content', $connection);

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $content = $_POST['content'];

    $ins = mysql_query("INSERT INTO msg (content) VALUES ('$content')");

    echo 'insert success';
    }else{
        echo 'failed';
        }
?>
```

Comment: could you please carefully rephrase your question. I can't seem to understand where you are going..

Comment: @PENDO, when I insert something in `index.php` ,the data will send to `2.php`. then I want get the word `insert success` or `failed` from `2.php` and show in `div#comment` in `index.php`. the return word could be have a fadein fadeout effection. I mean the word `insert success` first fadein in the `div#comment` then disappear. Thanks

Comment: see my 'solution' below (didnt have enough chars here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use the callback you get from your backend file.
Try this instead.

**EDIT:**  As Pendo mention below, you should use JSON when returning data from `2.php`.

**Edited version**

**Index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    // EDIT
    $('#comment').hide();         

    $("#submit").click(function(){
    var formvalue = $("#content").val();
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "2.php",
       data: 'content='+formvalue,
       dataType: 'json', // EDIT set dataType to json
       success: function(ret){
           $("#content").val('');
           if(ret['success'])
           {
              //Fade in 
              $('#comment').html('Insert Success!').fadeIn(1000);
              //Fade Out
              setTimeout(function(){ $('#comment').html('').fadeOut(1000); },1500);
           }else{
              // Fade in
              $('#comment').html('Insert Failed!').fadeIn(1000);
              // Fade out
              setTimeout(function(){ $('#comment').html('').fadeOut(1000); },1500);
           }
       }
     });
    });
});
```

```
<textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea> <br />
<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Add comment" />
<div id="comment"></div>
```

**2.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root' , 'root') or die(mysql_error());
$selection = mysql_select_db('my_content', $connection);
$content = $_POST['content'];

/* Set return data to false as default */
$json_ret = array('success'=>false);

$sql = "INSERT INTO msg (content) VALUES ('".$content."')";
if(mysql_query($sql))
{
  /* insert success.. add true  */
  $json_ret['success'] = true;
}

 echo json_encode($json_ret);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, @user741991, @PENDO, but I still want `insert success` with a `fadein` - `fadeout` effection. such as, when the date first insert, display  `insert success`, then 1 seconds later, `insert success` moved from `div#comment`.

Comment: @user741991, thanks, I have seen your updated answer, this is what i need.

Comment: Use this on setTimeout instead (fadeOut function). 
setTimeout(function(){ $('#comment').fadeOut(1000); },1500);

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your 2.php file is returning that that can be used by jQuery either a json object or javascript array. Then be sure that your success functions has access to the returned data, which is right now not the case.

In the example user741991 gave above me you can see the `data` object is being send along with the success function that is called after a succesfull ajax call. If it's a useable object you could use data.type and data.message (if the returned object would contain a key named 'type' and 'message').

Hopefully I've made myself clear, feels like I'm typing some non-understandable words right now.